# Can a signal be sent and received in the same point? What are the limitations?

Tags: special-relativity, popular-science, thought-experiment

I'm wondering about this scenario:

START: $B$ and $A$ moving to the right with speed $u$
$A$ present in point $X$ 
Signal $S$ with speed $v'$ sent by $A$ in point $X$ towards $B$
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    B @<S<< A\\
    @.  @|\\
     @. X
\end{CD}
END: $B$ reaches $X$ and receives the signal.Signal $S$ with speed $v'$ received by $B$ in point $X$
\begin{CD}
    B @<S<< A\\
    @|  @.\\
     X @.
\end{CD}

The scenario involves three speeds:

- $u$ - the speed of the inertial system moving right
- $v'$ - the speed of the signal as perceived by A and B, it should be so, that the signal reaches B in the same point X in the outer system
- $v$ - the speed of the signal as seen from point X, it should be $0$



  My questions:
- Can such a signal be sent at all?
- Could it be a light signal? Any other limitations?
- Could you give an example with explanation?

Please note it's tagged [popular-science](/questions/tagged/popular-science), so answer as simply as possible, but not more.

Comment: Please draw a diagram or something.  This is very hard to read on mobile browsers with the formatting block being wider than a screen.

Comment: @JMac Sorry, I can't draw. But the diagram is very simple. The system B....A consists of B and A. B on the left at some distance from A, who's on the right. They are moving to the right with speed u->. A is at the point X and sends a signal to the left, towards B, with speed <-v'. v' has to be so, that B will get the signal when he reaches point X. So the signal speed from the point of view of the point X would be equal 0.

Comment: you just aren't supposed to use the coding block like that.  It can cause trouble on mobile screens and with screen readers.  It really shouldn't be hard to make some lines on paint or something (anything really) besides trying to make a drawing with text; especially in the coding block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Non-relativistic scenario** 
 
If the speed of the signal is $v'$ according to the observers $A$ and $B$ moving with speed $u$ to the right then the speed of the signal observed from the stationary point $X$ will be the difference between the two velocities:
$$u-v'=v.$$
Where $v$ is the velocity of the signal observed from point $X$. If the signal's speed seems to be zero it means that
$$v'=u.$$
This can occur if the signal is carried by a piece of paper and it is thrown form point $A$ to point $B$ in space where no gravitation or air resistance has effects on their movements. This version is definitely possible to do. But let's get started, we want to know what happens when the signal's speed is the speed of light! 
**Relativistic scenario** 
We need to start with the most fundamental postulate of relativity: the speed of light is observed to be the same from any point of view. This means that it does not matter how fast I am moving, if I shine a laser in the opposite direction I am moving it will travel with the speed of light and won't "loose" even a bit of it's velocity even if I am moving with 99.9999999% the speed of light.(More on special relativity [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BFKqIoqSIY)) This means this experiment can not be done with light signals because nothing can slow down light! 
**Final conclusion** 
The experiment can not be done with any signals which are travelling with the speed of light(radio waves,visible light and any kind of electromagnetic waves)But it could be done with moving objects (even atoms or anything what has mass). I hope my answer was useful :)

Comment: We do however observe the phase velocity of light being changed under movement through space. The *two-way* phase velocity of light is only *locally* invariant *relative* to a local (co-moving) clock, which is not quite the same as saying the speed of light is the same from any point of view. In practice, we do observe asymmetric speeds of light - it can be (and already has been) experimentally verified by comparing the counters on atomic clocks and the asymmetric accrual of ticks under different relative movements (an asymmetry that is not accounted for by movement relative to each object).

Comment: At first: this question was tagged popular science so I did not wanted to introduce any non-neccessary terms and phenomena which could be confusing. Secondly: What do you mean by phase velocity? Are you talking about the red or blue shift of light? Then the assymmetry of phase velocity is real(and it is called doppler effect) but the speed of the propagation of light is not assymetric in any way.BTW phase velocity has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: I employ the phase velocity because that is the basic unit of signalling through waves, and it can be seen that if the wavelength is equal to the distance between A and B and adjusted for their speed relative to the frame, then B will finish receiving the signal at the same point that A began to transmit it. (1/3)

Comment: Of course you might say "aha, but then X is not the point that B began to receive the signal, nor is X the point that A finished emitting it", but that objection is inherent to the OP's scenario where he has defined X as a point. If you ask can the ranges partially overlap, the answer is yes, at very high speeds. (2/3)

Comment: If you ask can the ranges wholly coincide, the answer in wave theory is yes, if the objects are at the propagation speed of the medium - the wave will then act as a standing wave, waiting for B. I know that is thought not to be possible with light, but it can be done in theory where the medium of the wave is particulate, and it could also be done with light where A and B are heading into a gravitational field. (3/3)

Comment: A gravitational field? Then their velocities would not be the same anymore. And please don't let a tree cover the forest in front of you. Don't overcomplicate a simple problem.

Comment: Their relative velocity could be held the same (by accelerating differentially against the gravitational field). It is not an overcomplication - the theory allows what you say it does not. Even if we limit ourselves to SR (which wasn't a constraint imposed by the OP), it is not the inability to slow down light that prevents such signals being sent - which can be overcome by moving the signallers at the speed of light. The inability of real signallers to reach the speed of light in the first place is for complicated reasons that are auxilliary to the scenario (in which speed could be assumed)